This stream audio nextjs component failed in safari with howler.js
Hi all this component for audio streaming with howler works perfectly in chrome and firefox but failed in safari desktop (18.0.1) but I can't find why...
The logic is to play an intro and after load and play the webradio audio stream.
The live url is here https://freeradio.fr
If you have any ideas ;) Thanks
import { useEffect, useState, useRef, useCallback } from "react";
import { Howl } from "howler";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const CONFIG = {
  RETRY: {
    INITIAL_DELAY: 1000,
    MAX_DELAY: 32000,
    BACKOFF_FACTOR: 2,
    MAX_ATTEMPTS: 5,
  },
  BUFFER: {
    THRESHOLD: 2,
  },
  INTRO_URL: "/audio/intro.mp3",
};

const AudioPlayer = ({ streamUrl }) => {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false); // Nouvel état pour le chargement
  const [isFirstPlay, setIsFirstPlay] = useState(true);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);
  const [listeningTime, setListeningTime] = useState(0);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);
  const [volume, setVolume] = useState(1);
  const [showVolumeSlider, setShowVolumeSlider] = useState(false);
  const router = useRouter();
  const soundRef = useRef(null);
  const reconnectAttemptsRef = useRef(0);
  const isManuallyPausedRef = useRef(false); // Nouveau drapeau pour gérer la pause

  // Fonction de reconnexion avec backoff exponentiel
  const handleReconnect = useCallback(() => {
    //console.log("handleReconnect");
    const reconnectDelay = Math.min(
      CONFIG.RETRY.INITIAL_DELAY *
        Math.pow(CONFIG.RETRY.BACKOFF_FACTOR, reconnectAttemptsRef.current),
      CONFIG.RETRY.MAX_DELAY
    );

    reconnectAttemptsRef.current++;

    setTimeout(() => {
      setupHowler();
    }, reconnectDelay);
  }, [streamUrl]);

  
  // Initialisation du flux audio principal avec Howler.js
  const setupHowler = useCallback(() => {
    if (soundRef.current) soundRef.current.unload();

    setIsLoading(true); // Début du chargement du flux principal

    const proxyUrl0 = `https://stream.mydomain.fr?url=${streamUrl}`;
    const timestamp = Date.now();
    const proxyUrl = `${proxyUrl0}?_=${timestamp}`;
    //const proxyUrl = `${streamUrl}`;
    
    //console.log("stream", proxyUrl);

    soundRef.current = new Howl({
      src: [proxyUrl],
      html5: true,
      format: [
        "mp3",
        "mpeg",
        "opus",
        "ogg",
        "oga",
        "wav",
        "aac",
        "caf",
        "m4a",
        "m4b",
        "mp4",
        "weba",
        "webm",
        "dolby",
        "flac",
      ],
      volume: volume,
      autoUnlock: true,
      preload: true,
      pool: 1,
      xhr: {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
          'Pragma': 'no-cache'
        }
      },
      onplay: () => {
        setIsPlaying(true);
        isManuallyPausedRef.current = false;
        setIsLoading(false); // Fin du chargement du flux principal
        setError(null);
      },
      onloaderror: (id, error) => {
        console.error("Erreur de chargement audio (ID: " + id + "):", error);
        setError("Erreur de chargement du flux.");
        setIsLoading(false);
        handleReconnect();
      },
      onplayerror: (id, error) => {
        console.error("Erreur de lecture audio (ID: " + id + "):", error);
        setError("Erreur de lecture du flux.");
        setIsLoading(false);
        handleReconnect();
      },
      onend: () => {
        console.log("Stream ended, attempting to reconnect...");
        if (!isManuallyPausedRef.current) {
          handleReconnect();
        }
      },
    });

    soundRef.current.play();
  }, [streamUrl, handleReconnect, volume]);

  // Fonction de lecture de l'intro, sans lecture automatique
  const playIntro = useCallback(() => {
    if (soundRef.current) soundRef.current.unload();

    setIsLoading(true); // Début du chargement

    soundRef.current = new Howl({
      src: [CONFIG.INTRO_URL],
      html5: true,
      format: ["mp3"],
      volume: volume,
      autoUnlock: true,
      preload: true,
      pool: 1,
      onplay: () => {
        setListeningTime(0);
        setProgress(0);
      },
      onend: () => {
        console.log("Intro finished, starting stream...");
        setIsLoading(false); // Fin du chargement après l'intro
        //setupHowler(); // Démarre le flux principal après l'intro
        setIsFirstPlay(false);
      },
      onloaderror: (id, error) => {
        console.error("Error loading intro:", error);
        setError("Erreur de chargement de l'intro.");
        setIsLoading(false); // Fin du chargement même si l'intro échoue
        //setupHowler(); // Passe au flux principal même si l'intro échoue
        setIsFirstPlay(false);
      },
    });

    soundRef.current.play();
  }, [setupHowler, volume]);

  // Gestion de la lecture et de la pause
  const togglePlay = () => {
    if (isPlaying) {
      soundRef.current.pause();
      isManuallyPausedRef.current = true; // Marque que l'audio a été mis en pause
    } else {
      soundRef.current.play();
      isManuallyPausedRef.current = false; // Réinitialise lors de la lecture
    }
    setIsPlaying(!isPlaying);
  };

  const handlePlayButton = () => {
    if (isFirstPlay) {
      playIntro();
    } else {
      togglePlay();
    }
  };

  // Gestion du changement de volume
  const handleVolumeChange = useCallback((newVolume) => {
    const clampedVolume = Math.max(0, Math.min(1, newVolume));
    if (soundRef.current) {
      soundRef.current.volume(clampedVolume); // Utilisation de la méthode correcte
      setVolume(clampedVolume); // Mise à jour de l'état
    }
  }, []);

  // Effet pour le nettoyage lors des changements de route
useEffect(() => {
  const cleanup = () => {
    if (soundRef.current) {
      soundRef.current.unload();
      setIsPlaying(false);
      setIsLoading(false);
      setProgress(0);
      setListeningTime(0);
      reconnectAttemptsRef.current = 0;
      isManuallyPausedRef.current = false;
      setError(null);
    }
  };

  router.events.on("routeChangeStart", cleanup);
  window.addEventListener("beforeunload", cleanup);

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("beforeunload", cleanup);
    router.events.off("routeChangeStart", cleanup);
    cleanup();
  };
}, [router.events]);

// Effet pour gérer les changements de streamUrl
useEffect(() => {
  // Si c'est la première lecture, on ne démarre pas automatiquement
  if (isFirstPlay) {
    //console.log("isFirstPlay");
    return;
  }

  // Si l'URL du stream change, on redémarre le stream
  if (streamUrl) {
    //console.log("change streamUrl");
    // On nettoie d'abord l'existant
    if (soundRef.current) {
      soundRef.current.unload();
    }
    
    // On réinitialise les états
    setProgress(0);
    setListeningTime(0);
    reconnectAttemptsRef.current = 0;
    setError(null);
    
    // On démarre le nouveau stream
    setupHowler();
  }
}, [streamUrl, setupHowler, isFirstPlay]);

  // Effet pour le temps d'écoute et la progression
  useEffect(() => {
    let interval;
    if (isPlaying && !error) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        setProgress((prev) =>
          Math.min(99.9, prev + 0.02 / Math.pow(prev + 1, 2))
        );
        setListeningTime((prev) => prev + 0.1);
      }, 100);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, [isPlaying, error]);

  // Formatage du temps d'écoute
  const formatListeningTime = useCallback((time) => {
    const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
    const seconds = Math.floor(time % 60);

    const minutePart =
      minutes > 0 ? `${minutes} minute${minutes > 1 ? "s" : ""}` : "";
    const secondPart =
      seconds > 0 || minutes === 0
        ? `${seconds} seconde${seconds !== 1 ? "s" : ""}`
        : "";

    return `${minutePart} ${secondPart}`.trim();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="mt-4">
      <div className="flex items-center justify-between">
        <div onClick={handlePlayButton} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
          {isLoading ? (
            // Animation de chargement
            <svg
              className="animate-spin text-purple-600"
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              width="60"
              height="60"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
            >
              <rect width="24" height="24" fill="none" />
              <circle
                cx="12"
                cy="12"
                r="0"
                fill="currentColor"
                className="text-purple-600"
              >
                <animate
                  id="svgSpinnersPulseMultiple0"
                  fill="freeze"
                  attributeName="r"
                  begin="0;svgSpinnersPulseMultiple2.end"
                  calcMode="spline"
                  dur="1.2s"
                  keySplines=".52,.6,.25,.99"
                  values="0;11"
                />
                <animate
                  fill="freeze"
                  attributeName="opacity"
                  begin="0;svgSpinnersPulseMultiple2.end"
                  calcMode="spline"
                  dur="1.2s"
                  keySplines=".52,.6,.25,.99"
                  values="1;0"
                />
              </circle>
              <circle
                cx="12"
                cy="12"
                r="0"
                fill="currentColor"
                className="text-purple-600"
              >
                <animate
                  id="svgSpinnersPulseMultiple1"
                  fill="freeze"
                  attributeName="r"
                  begin="svgSpinnersPulseMultiple0.begin+0.2s"
                  calcMode="spline"
                  dur="1.2s"
                  keySplines=".52,.6,.25,.99"
                  values="0;11"
                />
                <animate
                  fill="freeze"
                  attributeName="opacity"
                  begin="svgSpinnersPulseMultiple0.begin+0.2s"
                  calcMode="spline"
                  dur="1.2s"
                  keySplines=".52,.6,.25,.99"
                  values="1;0"
                />
              </circle>
              <circle
                cx="12"
                cy="12"
                r="0"
                fill="currentColor"
                className="text-purple-600"
              >
                <animate
                  id="svgSpinnersPulseMultiple2"
                  fill="freeze"
                  attributeName="r"
                  begin="svgSpinnersPulseMultiple0.begin+0.4s"
                  calcMode="spline"
                  dur="1.2s"
                  keySplines=".52,.6,.25,.99"
                  values="0;11"
                />
                <animate
                  fill="freeze"
                  attributeName="opacity"
                  begin="svgSpinnersPulseMultiple0.begin+0.4s"
                  calcMode="spline"
                  dur="1.2s"
                  keySplines=".52,.6,.25,.99"
                  values="1;0"
                />
              </circle>
            </svg>
          ) : isPlaying ? (
            // Icône Pause
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              width="60"
              height="60"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              className="fill-current text-purple-600 hover:text-purple-700 dark:text-purple-500"
            >
              <path d="M9 16h2V8H9zm4 0h2V8h-2zm-1 6q-2.075 0-3.9-.788t-3.175-2.137T2.788 15.9T2 12t.788-3.9t2.137-3.175T8.1 2.788T12 2t3.9.788t3.175 2.137T21.213 8.1T22 12t-.788 3.9t-2.137 3.175t-3.175 2.138T12 22" />
            </svg>
          ) : (
            // Icône Play
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              width="60"
              height="60"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              className="fill-current text-purple-600 hover:text-purple-700 dark:text-purple-500"
            >
              <path d="M10 16.5v-9l6 4.5M12 2A10 10 0 0 0 2 12a10 10 0 0 0 10 10a10 10 0 0 0 10-10A10 10 0 0 0 12 2" />
            </svg>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="relative mx-4 h-2 grow rounded-full bg-slate-600 dark:bg-slate-600">
          <div
            className="absolute left-0 top-0 h-full bg-purple-600 dark:bg-purple-500"
            style={{
              width: `${progress}%`,
              height: "100%",
              transition: "width 0.1s",
            }}
          ></div>
        </div>
        <div className="relative ml-4">
          <button
            className="rounded-full p-2 text-white transition-colors hover:bg-slate-700"
            onClick={() => setShowVolumeSlider(!showVolumeSlider)}
            aria-label="volume control"
          >
            <svg
              xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
              width="1.5em"
              height="1.5em"
              viewBox="0 0 24 24"
              className="fill-current text-purple-600 hover:text-purple-700 dark:text-purple-500"
            >
              <rect width="24" height="24" fill="none" />
              <path
                fill="currentColor"
                d="M14 20.725v-2.05q2.25-.65 3.625-2.5t1.375-4.2t-1.375-4.2T14 5.275v-2.05q3.1.7 5.05 3.138T21 11.975t-1.95 5.613T14 20.725M3 15V9h4l5-5v16l-5-5zm11 1V7.95q1.175.55 1.838 1.65T16.5 12q0 1.275-.663 2.363T14 16"
              />
            </svg>
          </button>

          {showVolumeSlider && (
            <div className="absolute bottom-full left-1/2 mb-2 -translate-x-1/2 rounded-lg bg-slate-900 p-2 shadow-lg">
              <div className="flex h-32 w-12 flex-col items-center justify-center">
                <input
                  type="range"
                  min="0"
                  max="100"
                  value={volume * 100}
                  onChange={(e) => handleVolumeChange(e.target.value / 100)}
                  className="h-24 cursor-pointer appearance-none rounded-lg bg-slate-700 accent-purple-600"
                  style={{
                    writingMode: "vertical-lr",
                    direction: "rtl",
                    background: `linear-gradient(to top, #9333ea ${
                      volume * 100
                    }%, #334155 ${volume * 100}%)`,
                    WebkitAppearance: "none",
                  }}
                />
                <span className="mt-2 text-xs text-slate-400">
                  {Math.round(volume * 100)}%
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
      {!error && (
        <div className="mt-4 text-sm text-white">
          Durée d'écoute : {formatListeningTime(listeningTime.toFixed(1))}
        </div>
      )}

      {error && <p style={{ color: "red" }}>{error}</p>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default AudioPlayer;

my apache proxy for the stream
# Handle range requests properly
    RequestHeader set Range expr=%{HTTP:Range}
    RequestHeader set If-Range expr=%{HTTP:If-Range}

    # Extraction du paramètre url et redirection vers le flux cible
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)url=(http.*)
    RewriteRule ^/?(.*) %2 [P,L]

    # Proxy settings for streaming
    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
        # Enable handling of range requests
        Header merge Accept-Ranges bytes
        Header set Accept-Ranges bytes
        
        # Cache control headers
        Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Expires 0
        
        # Security headers
        Header always set X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff"
        Header always set X-Frame-Options "DENY"
        Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
    </Proxy>

    # Gestion des formats MIME basés sur l'extension du flux audio
    # MP3
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=.*\.mp3 [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=STREAM_TYPE:audio/mpeg]

    # AAC
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=.*\.aac [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=STREAM_TYPE:audio/aac]

    # OGG
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=.*\.ogg [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=STREAM_TYPE:audio/ogg]

    # OPUS
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=.*\.opus [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=STREAM_TYPE:audio/opus]

    # FLAC
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} url=.*\.flac [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=STREAM_TYPE:audio/flac]

    # En-tête Content-Type basé sur la variable d'environnement STREAM_TYPE
    Header set Content-Type "%{STREAM_TYPE}e" env=STREAM_TYPE

    # ProxyPass settings for better streaming handling
    ProxyTimeout 600
    ProxyBadHeader Ignore
    
    # Configure mod_proxy to handle range requests
    SetEnv proxy-sendcl 1
    SetEnv proxy-sendchunks 1
    #SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
    #SetEnvIf User-Agent "Safari" proxy-nokeepalive 1
    
    Header always set Connection "Keep-Alive"
    
    # Buffer size settings for streaming
    ProxyIOBufferSize 32768

    # Enable appropriate modules
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET, OPTIONS"
        Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Range,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type"

        # Ajout des en-têtes pour le streaming
        Header always set Accept-Ranges bytes
        Header set Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
        Header set Pragma "no-cache"
        Header set Expires 0
        Header set Connection "Keep-Alive"
    </IfModule>

Update: after several tests the problem is located in the proxy configuration for safari

"failed". Ok, but hat have you tried to start debugging? Errors in console?

yes of course and nothing really interesting ... sometime the stream works but after 3 times it failed... It's look like safari can't get the stream send by the apache proxy which perfectly works in chrome and firefox... So it's only a Safari probleme with icecast stream send by a SSL proxy...
I will update the problem with my apache conf
